# Wrong OG meta tag in wordpress posts when share a link on telegram

Tags: php, wordpress, share, meta-tags, posts

I have some problems when I share a wordpress post on telegram. meta tags are not displaying on true way. but in page view source it get true data. I don't know what's the problem. I write the follow code in header.php file.

```
<?php global $post; ?>

    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php 
    if(is_front_page()){
        echo get_bloginfo();
    }
    else
        echo the_title(); 

    ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo "eda website" ; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php 
    if(is_front_page())
        echo "http://eda-af.com";
    else    
        echo the_permalink(); 
    ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo(); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php
    if(is_front_page())
        echo "http://eda-af.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/meta_logo.jpg";
    else
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium');
        echo $img_src[0]; 
    ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer!
the problem was because telegram keeps link's cache.
so I used the google site for shorten my url ([goo.gl](http://goo.gl)) and also with telegram bot ([@webpagebot](http://t.me/webpagebot)).
the problem solved.